# Should i create all classes as spring beans

Tags: java, spring

I'm wondering when should I create class as Spring bean. Should all my classes be declared as such when using the Spring Framework container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only make Spring aware of those classes that need to be wired together making use of dependency injection and those that are required for configurational aspects.

Always ask yourself why should Spring need to know about the concrete class you are currently focusing on. For example like this:

- **Controller** ... to route incoming requests to the correct class and method
- **Service** ... to be injected into other services or controllers
- **Configuration** ... to be used to set up the Spring application context
- **Repository** ... to be injected into services.